# How to find missing time value(s) in a given range in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
|    id |    mtime |
...
|   101 | 12:00:00 |
|   102 | 12:01:00 |
|   103 | 12:03:00 |
|   104 | 12:07:00 |
|   105 | 12:08:00 |
|   106 | 13:00:00 |
...
```

Is there a way to query the table (range 12:00:00-13:00:00) to get a set **with missing values** like this:

```
|    mtime |
| 12:02:00 |
| 12:04:00 |
| 12:05:00 |
| 12:06:00 |
| 12:09:00 |
| 12:10:00 |
...
| 12:59:00 |
```

or at least first empty occurance:

```
|    mtime |
| 12:02:00 |
```

or last consecutive value, that breaks the chain:

```
|    mtime |
| 12:01:00 |
```

I was thinking about using `ADDTIME(time, '00:01:00')` somewhere in the query but I can't figure it out. Right now I barely believe it's achievable without more complex coding and multiple queries, but I hope I'm missing something.

Comment: If it's always minutes or similar, I'd make a table containing the minutes (sort of a Tally Table) and then OUTER join into that and then you'll have null for missing minute numbers.

Comment: Consider handling issues of this kind in your presentation layer/application level code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a table (TABLE2) which have time of a full day (if u really need at any date),
and write your query like this

`SELECT TABLE2.mtime FROM TABLE2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.mtime = TABLE2.mtime
WHERE TABLE1.mtime IS NULL`

also add condition for maximum and minimum time check, because TABLE2 have all dat times.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any other method to accomplish this procedure, but this one seems most clear. I've spent some time to make it work in my case (which is more complex problem) but I succeeded and can finally accept the answer. Thanks a lot!